# My discord bot will not send a welcome message, but is reading other messages. I am using discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

I am trying to create a basic discord bot and am currently trying to implement a welcome message. I am not getting an error message, it just doesn't do anything, and if I try and print a message to the console when a member joins, nothing happens. The on_message function works just fine, along with the on_ready.

```
#bot

import discord
TOKEN = ('top secret token')

client = discord.Client()
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await message.channel.send('Welcome!')
    print('New User Detected')




client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's see... hmm

does the bot know what `message` and `channel` are in the `on_member_join` event which has kwarg member. Nope, it doesn't!

message and channel aren't defined in an `on_member_join`. First, get the channel

`channel = client.get_channel(ChannelID)`
this will get you the channel you want to send your message to.
after that, we will simply use `channel.send("message")` to send the message.

The final code will look like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(ChannelID)
    await channel.send('Welcome!')
    print('New User Detected')
```

Comment: Hi, I used that exact code and it still is not giving me a message. I also tried putting the channel ID in where you have ChannelID, and still won't send.

Comment: I got it working, it was an issue with permissions.